# Can we force a fitted distribution to have the same mean as the data?

Tags: distributions, simulation, weibull-distribution

I have some rainfall data that I am fitting with a Weibull distribution. The mean of the rainfall data is 0.62, but the mean of the best-fit Weibull distribution is 0.69. As a result, when I simulate data from the fitted Weibull distribution, the simulated rainfall is slightly too high, on average. Would forcing the Weibull distribution to have the same mean be a reasonable thing to do, and if so, how would I go about it?

Update: more details - I am using maximum likelihood estimation to fit hourly precip. data, from which I have removed the zeros and standardized by the seasonal mean and standard deviation.

Comment: 1. How are you fitting this?2.  Is the mean more important to you than the rest of the distribution? (Certainly possible but you need to think about why say the standard deviation and the 25th percentile matter less) 3. Do you have enough data that the sample mean is certain to be close to the population mean? 4. What's the overall fit like? Is a Weibull a good choice? 5. Is this daily rainfall? If so how are you dealing with all the zeros?

Comment: @Glen_b: updated question. And I didn't think of it that way, but yeah, in my case, I do want the simulated mean equal to the observed mean. And yes, Weibull is a good fit, overall.

Comment: You require that $\hat{\lambda}\Gamma(1+1/\hat{k}) = \bar{Y}$ (using Wikipedia's parameterization of the Weibull) , but the question then is, given you're now using method of moments for that part how do you want to do the rest. Do you (i) want pure method of moments or (ii) do you want to maximize likelihood given that restriction -- or indeed (iii) do you want to do something else?

Comment: Never mind, I did both, and then showed one method under (iii) as well.

Answer (score 3):

I use Wikipedia's parameterization here:

$$f(x;\lambda,k) = \begin{cases} \frac{k}{\lambda}\left(\frac{x}{\lambda}\right)^{k-1}e^{-(x/\lambda)^{k}} & x\geq0, \\ 0 & x<0. \end{cases}$$

Matching the first moment, we have $\hat{\lambda}\,\Gamma(1+1/{\hat{k}}) = \bar{Y}$.

1. Pure method of moments

   The $n$th raw moment is $\lambda^n \Gamma\left(1+\frac{n}{k}\right)$

   So we solve the nonlinear equation $\overline{Y^2}/\bar{Y}^2 = \Gamma(1+2/{\hat{k}})/\,\Gamma(1+1/{\hat{k}})^2$ for $\hat{k}$.

   The log of that ratio of gamma functions is locally fairly straight in ${1}/{\hat{k}}$, so that would be quite suitable for plugging into a root-finder (though you can even just do it by hand if it's a one-off problem, it's a couple of minutes work at most). For a problem I needed to do this with several times I'd use `uniroot` in R, it's easy and will work well for this.

   You then get $\hat{\lambda}$ from $\hat{\lambda} = \bar{Y}/\Gamma(1+1/{\hat{k}})$.
2. Mixed method of moments and MLE

   Given $k$, the MLE of $\lambda$ is ${\displaystyle {\widehat {\lambda }}=({\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{k})^{{1}/{k}}}$

   We can substitute the restriction to reproduce the sample mean given in 1, $\hat{\lambda}\Gamma(1+\frac{1}{\hat{k}})= \bar{Y}$, giving the nonlinear equation:

   $\Gamma(1+1/{\hat{k}})({\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{\hat{k}})^{1/{\hat{k}}}=\bar{Y}$

   to solve. Again, this should be reasonably straightforward with a decent rootfinding algorithm (or indeed even by hand if you're only doing it once), and again you can "straighten" the curve up a bit which should speed things up.

   You then get $\hat{\lambda}$ from $\hat{\lambda} = \bar{Y}/\Gamma(1+1/{\hat{k}})$.
3. Mixed method of moments and method of quantiles.

   One could take advantage of the fact that the $1-1/e\,(\approx 0.632)$ quantile of a Weibull is $\lambda$, independent of $k$, and so use quantile-matching to obtain $\hat{\lambda}$ and then solve $\Gamma(1+1/{\hat{k}}) = \bar{Y}/\hat{\lambda}$ for $\hat{k}$.

All of these methods should reproduce the sample mean. They all involve at least some iterative calculation. They are not all equally efficient (in the variance-of-the-estimator sense).